# Why filtering out null map keys doesn't change type to not nullable in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of objects with an optional id as String and I want to make a map out of it.
I want to have the keys of my map as non nullable: so something like this:

```
data class Foo(
  val id: String? = null
  val someStuff: String? = null,
)

val foo = listOf(Foo("id1"), Foo())
val bar = foo.filterNot { it.id == null }.associateBy { it.id }
```

Here `bar` type is `Map<String?, Foo>` but not `Map<String, Foo>`

My workaround is to add a non null asserted call: `!!`, but it doesn't seem clean.

Is there an easy and safe way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like something that `contracts` could help with, but currently a `contract` expression can't access properties of the class in use.

As a workaround, you could define a 2nd class that has a non-null `id`, like so

```
data class Foo(
    val id: String? = null,
    val someStuff: String? = null
)

data class Foo2(
    val id: String,
    val someStuff: String? = null
)

val foo = listOf(Foo("id1"), Foo())
val bar = foo
    .mapNotNull { if (it.id != null) Foo2(it.id, it.someStuff) else null }
    .associateBy { it.id }
```

Comment: My Foo class has a lot of fields, duplicating it is not a very convenient workaround, but I see your point that the mapNotNull will do the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's a [six-year-old open feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4734?_ga=2.99818140.309189619.1585055442-370803150.1565276011) for `Map.filterNotNullKeys()` and a [four-year old open feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14041) for `Map.associateByNotNull()`.

In my opinion, the `associateBy { it.id!! }` would be cleanest for readability. But you could do it like this:

```
val bar = foo.mapNotNull { it.id?.run { it.id to it } }.toMap()
```

As for your actual question, that logic is way too many steps for the compiler to infer. Your last function call to `associateBy` sees a nullable, so it infers a nullable. For the compiler to figure this out, it would have to step back and see that the List that you call `associateBy` on happens to have filtered out certain objects in a way that happens to ensure that a certain nullable property won't be null within this specific list, and it's the same property that you are associating with. Now imagine it has to do this for every call to any generic function, and the various lambdas involved could potentially have multiple lines of code. Compile times would skyrocket.